# Rule to send out content of newly created forum-topic or comment

Tags: rules

I have a rule that will send me an email with the username of the person that creates a new comment or forum-topic. However, I would really like the URL and actual content to show up in the email. How can I accomplish this in that order of importance. Because right now I have to click on content on the site and look for the newest items to find the new content.

Comment: There are tokens available in Show Replacement patterns, you can use that for embedding them in the email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using rules, you can send the URL of the updated content as per the solution provided by @[mohit_rocks](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/1022/mohit-rocks), but I was not able to find a solution to send the content / body (full / teaser) in the mail, using rules.

If you wish to send the content of the body too, you'll need to take help of the [Notify module](https://drupal.org/project/notify).

Steps to enable the send mails with the content of forum/topic in mail with the help of notify module:

1. Download and install notify module.
2. Under *admin > people > permissions*, set give the permission of *access notify* to the user role you wish the mails to go to. **Note:** The users of these roles need to enable the notification to enable receiving of the mails. You can keep this role limited to admin and let admins decide who receives the mail by following next step.
3. Go to *admin > config > people >notify* and enable notification for *forum* content type: [image: snap2] If you set time less than the time of your cron run, still the mail will be sent on cron run.
4. Go to *user > uid > notify* (replace uid with the the user id of the user). Admins can go to *admin > people* select *edit* against any user, and go to *Notification settings* tab and check the following options: [image: snap1]  You can check the *Title + Body + Fields* under *Detailed settings* section to send the values in fields as well.
5. To check the list of users who will receive the mails, go to *admin > config > people > notify > users*:[image: snap3]
6. That's it! Now the selected users should start receiving the notifications mails with content!

**Note:** If you have revisions enabled for the content type, and want to be notified when the content is edited, then check [this feature request](https://drupal.org/node/1842634) I've made at the module's issue queue. I've also created a [patch for the same](https://drupal.org/node/1842634#comment-6766498). If you have such requirement, then you can test the patch. If you post your findings on the issue, it'll be appreciated!

Comment: Great !! Even i was also not aware with this module..Thanks

Comment: Sure..i will take a look

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the parameters in the Rules module. See the screenshot below
[image]

By adding these parameters you can send any content /latest added contetn to mail body.
When you click on **Edit** link of send mail, you will find the follwoing page and you can send any content you want to send.

[image]